# Where can I find the declaration of "inputs" in this PHP code?

Tags: php

In a `php` code I found the code snippet:

```
class GF_Field extends stdClass implements ArrayAccess {

    if ( is_array( $this->inputs ) ) {
        foreach ( $this->inputs as $input ) {
```

But I don't know what is `inputs` come from.

Any help would be highly appropriated.

**EDIT:**

The programmer made two ambiguous step, which made me harder to find the declaration:

1. Declared an object instance's property in the code as Felippe pointed below
2. Made an assignment via referenced variable somewhere else in the code:

`foreach ( $this->inputs as &$input ) {
$input = something`

Comment: Start tracing it back. Do a search in your code for the definition.

Comment: It could be _anywhere_ in your codebase.  There's no way for us to know.

Comment: @aynber Of course I tried to trace it back. Here http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php I didn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ommiting code here, but for short answer, you don't have to explicitally define the attributes in PHP. You can create only for the object, and it will work like this:

```
class AnyClass extends stdClass {

    public function print() {
        if ( is_array( $this->inputs ) ) {
            foreach ( $this->inputs as $input ) {
                echo $input;
            }
        }
    }
}

$obj = new AnyClass;
$obj->inputs = [1,2,3];
$obj->print();
```

It will output `123`.

[stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) is a generic class for PHP objects. [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) is a PHP interface. So, in your case, the `$inputs`is probably not defined anywhere in the class, or class tree, but is "defined" directly in the object instance.

Comment: No problem. As you can see, the language allows the programmer to do this, but it doesn't seems to be a good practice. You should avoid that. And if this answer helped you, please mark as accepted.

Comment: Felippe, thank you again, accidentally I deleted my previous comment :)

Comment: Well, if I got it, here would be adequate to declare a simple variable, there is no need to declare it as an instance property.